# How can I have a vertical nav bar link move left when hovered over?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transitions, css-position

I've been playing around with CSS and creating nav bars. I'm trying to create an effect where the selected link in the nav bar will move our slightly to the left when hovered to indicate selection.
I'm not too sure where I'm going wrong, but I think it's safe to assume there's probably a few places since this is my first attempt at putting learning into practice.

I think where I'm going wrong is with the display or positioning properties, or possibly a conflict?

I tried playing with different display and positioning properties, but I'd like the nav bar to stick to its location whilst scrolling so as far as I know it would need to remain sticky. I tried changing padding and margin too.

At current when hovered over, instead of the one link hovered over moving, all others move, and strangely some move differently to others. Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated :)

**HTML:**

```html
    <div class="nav-container">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="nav-button"><a href="#"><span class="nav-num">01.</span> About</a></li>
                <li class="nav-button"><a href="#"><span class="nav-num">02.</span> Experience</a></li>
                <li class="nav-button"><a href="#"><span class="nav-num">03.</span> Work</a></li>
                <li class="nav-button"><a href="#"><span class="nav-num">04.</span> Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.nav-container {
    display: flex;
    position: sticky;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 6rem;
    line-height: 5rem;
    list-style: none;
    border-right: 1px grey solid;
    padding-right: 1.5rem;
}
.nav-container ul, a{
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: menlo;
    font-size: 0.7rem;
    color: #CCD6F6;
}
.nav-num {
    color: #6683FC;
}
.nav-button:hover{
    padding-left: 50px;
    transition: 1s linear;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using `transform: translateX` to move elements instead of adjusting padding:

```css
.nav-container {
  display: flex;
  position: sticky;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 6rem;
  line-height: 5rem;
  list-style: none;
  border-right: 1px grey solid;
  padding-right: 1.5rem;
}

.nav-container ul,
a {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: menlo;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  color: #CCD6F6;
}

.nav-num {
  color: #6683FC;
}

.nav-button {
  transition: 0.1s ease;
}

.nav-button:hover {
  transform: translateX(10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-container">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="nav-button"><a href="#"><span class="nav-num">01.</span> About</a></li>
      <li class="nav-button"><a href="#"><span class="nav-num">02.</span> Experience</a></li>
      <li class="nav-button"><a href="#"><span class="nav-num">03.</span> Work</a></li>
      <li class="nav-button"><a href="#"><span class="nav-num">04.</span> Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with that approach is when you move the whole element if the cursor is located in between those 10px, it passes from active to inactive, so the element returns and gets active again, generating an infinite "shaky" loop.

Comment: Thank you Human Bean, that worked for my intended use. I'm new to the transform property so have played around with its different uses and values a bit. I understand the drawbacks Alvin mentioned and have been able to recreate them with scale, but not through positioning, at least with such a small transition.